# How to add two date interval in the same labels using PHP Gantti

Tags: php, mysql

I have used the PHP Gantt Class from Github here: https://github.com/bastianallgeier/gantti

I have a php script which generates a gantt chant from data in a php array:

```
// $reservations is an array from db
$data = array();
    foreach ($reservations as $value) {
        $class = ($value['statut'] == 0) ? '' : 'urgent';
        $data[] = array(
            'label' => $value['chambre'],
            'start' => $value['date_debut'],
            'end' => $value['date_fin'],
            'libelle' => $value['libelle'],
            'class' => $class
        );
    }
```

Et quand il ya deux résultat ayant le même label il y a duplication. How to merge them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it was resolved by https://github.com/bastianallgeier/gantti/pull/9

We remembered the last Id and if it's the same, merge it in the same cols.